# npm run-script myScript arguments

Tags: node.js, npm

According to the website https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

```
npm run-script <command> [-- <args>...]
```

Where can I find a list of these arguments?

Comment: Have you tried `npm -h` or `npm --help`?

Comment: @nathanhleung Yes doesn't give me detailed docs unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

It just means that everything after the `--` is passed directly to the invoked script. There is no fixed list of arguments, you define them yourself.

Example :

```
// Package.json :
"myscript": "node ./myfile.js"

// myfile.js :
console.log(process.argv[2]); 

// Command :    
npm run-script myscript -- foobar // prints 'foobar'
```